# Homeomorphic product spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

In his text book on descriptive set theory, Proposition 25.2, Kechris implicitely uses the fact that $(\omega \times \omega)^\omega$ and $\omega^\omega \times \omega^\omega$ are homeomorphic, where $\omega$ denotes the set of non-negative integers and carries the discrete topology.

Actually, the following is not hard to see (if I did not make a mistake):

> Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be discrete spaces and let $Y$ be a set. Then the product spaces $X_1^Y \times \ldots \times X_n^Y$ and $(X_1 \times \ldots \times X_n)^Y$ are homeomorphic.

I would need a reference for this fact.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: By induction you can assume $n=2$. Hint: If $f:Y\to X_1\times X_2$ then $f(y)=(f_1(y),f_2(y))$.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hom-functor+preserves+limits

Comment: Map $(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ in the first space to the map $y \to (f_1(y),\ldots,f_n(y))$ in the second. There is no choice. Discreteness matters not.